# Cómo asignar valor a textbox con jquery en asp.net vb

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, textbox

Mi pregunta es algo básica pero no he podido dar con el código correcto.

esta es una página asp.net con visual basic, y tengo un campo textBox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="n_terminal" runat="server" TextMode="Number" ReadOnly="True" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

Al cual le quiero asignar un valor y he probado con:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var obj = document.DemoActiveX;

    var bod = obj.GetRegistry('Cod_Bodega');
    var ter = obj.GetRegistry('Cod_Terminal');

    alert(ter); //esto es para que muestre el valor y lo hace

    $('#n_terminal').val(ter);
</script>
```

Pero no pasa nada.

Tengo claro que cuando ejecuto mi aplicación el id del textbox cambia, en mi caso pasa a ser:

```
<input name="ct100$MainContent$n_terminal" class="form-control" id="MainContent_n_terminal" type="number" readonly="readonly">
```

y he probado con:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var obj = document.DemoActiveX;

    var bod = obj.GetRegistry('Cod_Bodega');
    var ter = obj.GetRegistry('Cod_Terminal');

    alert(ter); //esto es para que muestre el valor y lo hace

    $('#MainContent_n_terminal').val(ter);
</script>
```

Y tampoco nada, ¿estoy haciendo algo mal? Probé con **.text**

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Parece que intentas usar jquery y tu script de un modo externo. Los estás linkeando en el head o al final del body?

Comment: en el head, pero en qué afectaría eso?

Comment: Por un tema de [block rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931103/jquery-in-external-javascript-file-in-asp-net), prueba poniéndolos antes del cierre del body.

Comment: creo que fue na mezcla de donde poner el jquery y la respuesta de Duston

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traducido de https://forums.asp.net/t/1522697.aspx?Getting+the+ClientID+of+ASP+NET+server+controls+in+external+js+files

Si queire usar jQuery para alcanzar un Web control definido ASP.NET, use:

```
$('#<%= Button1.ClientID %>')
```

o afuera del jQuery :

```
document.getElementById('<%= Button1.ClientID %>')
```

Comment: Gracias, entre tu respuesta y el comentario de dejar el jquery al final del documento pude cargar el dato a mi textbox